# AngularJS is always downloading files no matter that the browser settings are

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a NodeJS application with an AngularJS frontend. If a user requests a file, it is streamed from the node application to the angular frontend. But the frontend is always downloading the file, no matter that the browser settings are (for example: Firefox is set to open PDF files instead of downloading them by default).

The coding is als follows:

NodeJS

```
[...]
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': file.mimetype,
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${file.filename};`
    });
let readStream = BlobStore.createReadStream(fileId);

return readStream.pipe(res);
[...]
```

AngularJS HTML:

```
[...]
<a class="download-link" href="/api/files/{{file._id.toString()}}" target="_self" flex>
[...]
```

I also tried to convert the stream into a Blob, but that also did not do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was quite easy: According to the following docu to Content-Disposition header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) there is another parameter `inline` available.

So all i had to do was changing NodeJS coding to:

```
[...]
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': file.mimetype,
    'Content-Disposition': `inline; filename=${file.filename};`
    });
let readStream = BlobStore.createReadStream(fileId);

return readStream.pipe(res);
[...]
```